# Refreshing a vue component from a vue-router route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a view in my SPA that is loaded via vue router when a user types in a id in my sidebar. The component loads up and the prop is passed correctly through the route but if I type into the sidebar another id to load up I get this in console:

"vue-router.min.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/mainreview/search?id=1560".

My search functionality is using push() from a axios request to confirm that id exists and returns that as an array then pushes the component:

```
router.push({ path: '/mainreview/search', query: { mmcid: this.id[0].ID } });
```

My route is as follows:

```
 { path: '/mainreview/search', component: mainreview, props: route => ({ id: route.query.id })}
```

Most posts I have found on here seem to recommend suppressing the error but in my case I want it to reload the component so that the mount function inside the component runs again which is what triggers my an axios call with all my data.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an `id` and no other query param is needed, why don't just use it as url param?

```
{ 
    path: '/mainreview/search/:id', 
    component: mainreview, 
    props: true
}
```

Then you can push

```
router.push({ path: '/mainreview/search', params: { id: this.id[0].ID } });
```

Comment: Using this approach how do you pass the id to the component then if not through a prop? Also, when using this approach does it allow the mount() function to be called again on each page load?

Comment: By setting `props: true` in router you will receive the `:id` param as a prop in your `mainreview` component. You don't need to re-mount your component, instead, you can take advantage of component reusability and use a watcher for the `id` props. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Comment: Because this method seems to accomplish the same thing as my original query parameter, What is the benefit of using a url param vs a query param? Is the warning no longer triggered?